# обработка всех строк в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Пытаюсь по нажатию кнопки обработать все строки в гриде.
В моем случае есть грид с сообщениями

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь "прочитать" все сообщения по нажатию кнопки

```
 private void readAllBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in postsDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                ReadMessage();                              
            }
            GetData();           
        }
```

Метод для отметки сообщений как прочитанные

```
private void ReadMessage()
    {
        try
        {
            if (postsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells.Count > 0)
            {
                cs = cs.LoadFile();
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs.ToString()))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        int rowindex = postsDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                        int selectId = Convert.ToInt32(postsDataGridView.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Value);
                        string currentStream = (string)postsDataGridView.Rows[rowindex].Cells[5].Value;                                                                 //Получаем в переменную направление сообщения
                        string querryRead = String.Format("update sta_Messages set \"GetDate\" = CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(8)) where \"id\" = {0}", selectId);
                        if (currentStream == "вхідне")                                                                                                                  //Проверка, если входящее - сообщение прочитано
                        {
                            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querryRead, conn);
                            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                            //MessageBox.Show("Повідомлення прочитано");
                        }
                        else
                            MessageBox.Show("Відмічати можна тільки вхідні повідомлення");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Виберіть повідомлення");

        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Метод `GetData();` нужен для обновления грида после чтения сообщений.
Проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии на кнопку читается только первое сообщение, остальные остаются, в отладчике показывает что в цикле проходится по всем строкам, но по факту обрабатывается только первая.
Итого после нажатия выход такой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять в чем причина. 
спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы зачем-то прогоняете многократной цикл, вызывая один и тот же метод, который не имеет параметров:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow item in postsDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                ReadMessage();                              
            }
```

А тут, как я понимаю:

```
int rowindex = postsDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

Выбирается текущая строка, которая выделена.

Наверное, вам нужно в `ReadMessage` добавить параметр и передавать туда `DataGridViewRow`  и с ней работать.

Comment: `private void ReadMessage(DataGridViewRow rowindex  )` так я понимаю? и в цикле возвращаем `ReadMessage(item );` ?

Comment: Да, я думаю, что как-то так логичнее будет.

Comment: у меня возникает ошибка `System.InvalidCastException: Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow" к типу "System.IConvertible".` Пытаюсь сконвертировать `DataGridViewRow`  в `int`

Comment: @erleug ну так вам вот этот кусок переделать нужно postsDataGridView.Rows[rowindex]. Теперь у вас нет необходимости в этом, так как вы передаете все снаружи.

Comment: его я и переделываю, мне чтобы получить id нужно в `postsDataGridView.Rows[rowindex]` сам `rowindex` переконвертировать в `int`. Может не правильно понял

Comment: @erleug зачем вам индекс теперь? Вы снаружи пробрасываете готовенькую строку в свой метод ReadMessage. В индексе строки нет теперь необходимости. Работайте с тем, что пробросили.

Comment: `int selectId = Convert.ToInt32(postsDataGridView.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Value);` мне эта строка нужна чтобы получить id сообщения из БД, я его подставляю в запрос. А переменная интовая

Comment: @erleug int selectId = Convert.ToInt32(rowindex.Cells[0].Value); Теперь это должно выглядеть так.

Comment: понял, спасибо. И подскажете еще вопрос, на кнопке, где должно читаться только одно выбранное сообщение, что возвращаем в метод? Я так понимаю нужно получить выделенную строку и ее вернуть?

Comment: @erleug под возвращаем вы имеете ввиду передаем в ReadMessage? Ну, как я понимаю, все тоже самое, но вы должны выполнять итерацию не по всем строчкам, а по https://stackoverflow.com/a/3578190/4244707

Comment: да, есть еще одна кнопка, которая делает прочитанным только одно сообщение на выбранной строке. Я понял, что нужно получить индекс выделенной строки, но не догнал, как ее переконвертировать в `DataGridViewRow ` чтобы передать в `ReadMessage`

Comment: Вообщем сделал таким же образом, только в методе `ReadMessage` сделал проверку, какая кнопка нажата и в соответствии с этим выполняется свой код (получение индекса строки и подставление в запрос)